# Integration by substitution—total differential swaps

Tags: integration

I'm familiar with the elementary integration by substitution. For the following integral use $u = x+1$, so $\textrm{d}u = \textrm{d}x$

$$\int_b^a\textrm{d}x\,(x+1)\,f(x+1) = \int_{b+1}^{a+1}\textrm{d}u\,u\,f(u).$$

What I think is missing from my teaching of the material was what technique you use to understand the new variables. In one dimension I thought I was using the total differential to compute the new integration.

Now in a two dimensional case, let $z = x+y$, so $\textrm{d}z = \textrm{d}x + \textrm{d}y$, if we are thinking differentials, $\textrm{d}x \rightarrow \textrm{d}z - \textrm{d}y$.

$$\int_b^a\textrm{d}x\,(x+y)\,f(x+y) = \int_{b+y}^{a+y}(\textrm{d}z-\textrm{d}y)\,z\,f(z)\,\,(?)$$

Perhaps this is still techniquely correct, but not a good way to think about it. I believe the correct thing to do is say $\textrm{d}x \rightarrow \textrm{d}z$. Should I think of it as the variable $y$ is constant in the integral so the $\textrm{d}y = 0$, or the total derivative of $z$ with respects to $x$ is

$$\frac{\textrm{d}z}{\textrm{d}x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\textrm{d}x}{\textrm{d}x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x} =1 \rightarrow \textrm{d}z = \textrm{d}x.$$

Which boils down to y being independent of x, which is the same thing. I am just hoping for someone to guide me in the correct way of thinking about this process.

Testing this guess, let's use the same example and say y is no longer independent of x, so it's really a one dimensional problem again. Would the work then be: $z = x+y(x)$ and $\textrm{d}z = \textrm{d}x +\textrm{d}x \frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x} = (1 + y'(x))\textrm{d}x$

$$\int_b^a\textrm{d}x\,(x+y(x))\,f(x+y(x)) = \int_{b+y(x)}^{a+y(x)}\textrm{d}z\,(1+y'(x))^{-1}\,z\,f(z).$$

Clearly not a good substitution, but is the machinery correct?